# Optional parameters at SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, prepared-statement, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a raw SQL to be executed in SQLAlchemy with optional parameters coming from a query string.

I did a function to build the sentences to a where clause:

```
def queryParams(self, params):
    params = urllib.parse.parse_qs(params)
    query = ""
    for (key, val) in params.items():
        for value in val:
            if(re.match("/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/", value) != False or (value == "false" or value == "true")):
                query += ' AND ' + key + ' = ' + value
            else:
                query += ' AND ' + key + ' = ' + "'" + value + "'"

    return query
```

The problem is when I need to execute the query, I have to concat this to a SQL string and it's not good for a SQL Injection happening.

```
    s = text(
        'select a.cod_lim_judicial, a.desc_lim_judicial, a.dt_lim_judicial, '
        'a.dt_validade, a.nr_mandado, a.tipo_liminar, a.folhas_incidencia, '
        'a.num_folha, a.mes_ano_folha, p.mat_servidor, p.cod_depend, a.perc_pa '
        'from folha.fl_liminar a, folha.fl_pens_x_liminar p '
        'where a.cod_lim_judicial = p.cod_lim_judicial (+)' + self.queryParams(parameters))
    result = conn.execute(s).fetchall()
```

How can I use optional parameters using prepared statement?

Thanks to advance!

Comment: what's wrong with using **SQLAlchemy** to construct the query?

Comment: Note that [`re.match("/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/", value) != False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match) is going to be True always, since `re.match()` returns either a match object or None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a somewhat simplified example of what you could do:

```
In [42]: def queryParams(params):
    ...:     params = urllib.parse.parse_qs(params)
    ...:     for key, val in params.items():
    ...:         # Trust the implicit conversions:
    ...:         # https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-6DB331B5-0F34-4215-9A20-16AEA9D7FF4B
    ...:         yield column(key) == val
    ...:
```

Using [`column()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) handles quoting reserved words and mixed case, and escaping bad characters in column names, but you should still possibly whitelist though. The comparison produces a binary SQL expression object, with the bound parameter `val`. You can combine [Core constructs with text fragments](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-text-fragments-inside-bigger-statements) in order to generate your query:

```
In [43]: params = 'asdf=1&qwer=true&foo=baz'

In [44]: s = select([text("""
    ...:         a.cod_lim_judicial, a.desc_lim_judicial, a.dt_lim_judicial,
    ...:         a.dt_validade, a.nr_mandado, a.tipo_liminar, a.folhas_incidencia,
    ...:         a.num_folha, a.mes_ano_folha, p.mat_servidor, p.cod_depend, a.perc_pa""")]).\
    ...:     select_from(
    ...:         outerjoin(
    ...:             text("folha.fl_liminar a"),
    ...:             text("folha.fl_pens_x_liminar p"),
    ...:             text("a.cod_lim_judicial = p.cod_lim_judicial"))).\
    ...:     where(and_(*queryParams(params)))
    ...: 


In [45]: print(s)
SELECT 
        a.cod_lim_judicial, a.desc_lim_judicial, a.dt_lim_judicial,
        a.dt_validade, a.nr_mandado, a.tipo_liminar, a.folhas_incidencia,
        a.num_folha, a.mes_ano_folha, p.mat_servidor, p.cod_depend, a.perc_pa 
FROM folha.fl_liminar a LEFT OUTER JOIN folha.fl_pens_x_liminar p ON a.cod_lim_judicial = p.cod_lim_judicial 
WHERE asdf = :asdf_1 AND qwer = :qwer_1 AND foo = :foo_1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question. How do I pass those values through execute() since I have a key-value syntax?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get you. The values have already been bound as params to the statement construct. The `print(s)` simply displays he query's statement, but the object also contains the params.

Comment: So in order to execute the `select()` construct assigned to `s`, simply `execute(s)`.

Comment: I printed like you said and it comes like your example, but when i try to execute it, says that SQL was not properly ended

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Oracle and didn't know that the AS keyword in aliasing a table is illegal in Oracle. Removed it from the example. If you're using an old enough version of Oracle, then the (now) standard left join syntax is illegal as well and you'll have to revert to using the `(+)`.

Comment: Well, SQLAlchemy actually detects Oracle 8 and [does the right thing for joins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html#oracle-8-compatibility), so no need to manually revert.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11.2. I know the printing is not necessary. I just printed to verify if its correct syntax. And yes, the AS keyword is illegal in Oracle, but I'm not using this keyword and i didnt see it in your example.

Comment: It was there, but I edited them out. If you happened to use that version verbatim, then that at least would result in the error.

Comment: Oh that's true. I was using your example. It's my mistake too. I should have realized that before. Thank you very much again!